Changing data from DD/MM/YYYY to mySQL format YYYY-MM-DD
I am currently trying to get the data that I loaded from a .txt file to show the data in a way that I can manipulate it via excel's YEAR(function). The raw data date format looks like this:
01/03/2018

I have it loaded in as a VARCHAR at the moment so that the date at least shows in my data. I would like to convert it to:
2018-01-03

My current method is:
UPDATE Schema.Table
SET Admit_Date = str_to_date(Admit_Date, '%d/%m/%Y')

But I get the following error

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'Admit_Date' for function
str_to_date

I have looked this up but with no success to my specific issue making me think that this is a issue with how I have my table set up. Can someone help with my problem? Thanks!

Perhaps some of your values are not in dd/mm/yyyy format

So is your example supposed to be January 3rd or March 1st? Based on your update query, you should get 2018-03-01 which is March 1st. But you want 2018-01-03 which is January 3rd. Something isn't right with your question. Try changing to '%m/%d/%Y') because I think you simply have D and M mixed around, which would cause the error because there are no months beyond 12.

I think the column is storing the literal string 'Admit_Date'. That error would be returned if the data were that string.

I don't really understand what you want do to. Why not simply use a date column and save a date there? You usually don't need to change the format in the DB. Do that in a query using date functions. Could you better explain your use cases?

@Shadow This was the issue. I did not delete the header of the file which ended up loading in.

@Isolated Sorry about the the lack of clarity. It is supposed to be Jan 1st.  And yes this was my mistake I tried doing %d/%m/%Y as an attempt to get something to work and I forgot to change it back to the original. My mistake but thank you as that is the correct format.

@JonasMetzler First, thank you for editing the formatting. Second, I did try setting the column to a DATE, but when the dates came through, they appeared as 0000-00-00. The raw data I can not change as it is hundreds of thousands of rows of data. My logic was that I would load in the dates as the VARCHAR so they appeared, and then would convert them to the actual format later. I need these as a DATE so that I can use the YEAR function, and others, to analyze the data. Hopefully that helped clear it up. I was able to fix the issue as there was header information in my data that I did not scrub

Try '%m/%d/%Y'. I believe some of your data is making this mistake where it is reading the days as months.

That was part of the issue and my mistake as I originally was using '%m/%d/%Y', but during my testing I made the mistake of not switching it back for this post. The actual issue was due to Header text of the file I loaded being in the data and me not deleting it.
